# Как сравнить параметры одного объекта со всеми другими объектами в массиве?

Tags: java

Есть задача: едут поезда из пункта А (0) в пункт Б (100). У каждого поезда своя скорость и в за каждый шаг поезд переезжает на столько, сколько его скорость. при этом скорости рандомные (от 1 до 10) и нельзя поезду ехать, если точка, в которой он окажется уже занята. Я сделал поезда, они ездят и всё у всех хорошо, но! Не могу понять как выполнить последнее условие и как поезду перед поездкой посмотреть, можно ли ему ехать или нет, т.е. занята точка или нет? поезда друг друга не обгоняют вообще. Например: 1ый поезд едет первый на 5 шагов. Второй может ехать на 4 и меньше. Если у всех последующих скорость выше 5, то они стоят на месте

**Класс поезда:**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Train {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private int speed;
    private String types[] = {"Грузовой", "Пассажирский"};
    private int whereAmI;

    public int getWhereAmI() {
        return whereAmI;
    }

    public void setWhereAmI(int whereAmI) {
        this.whereAmI = whereAmI;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public Train(String name) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int minSpeed = 1;
        int maxSpeed = 10;
        this.name = name;
        this.speed = rand.nextInt(maxSpeed) + minSpeed;
        this.type = types[rand.nextInt(2)];
        this.whereAmI = 0;
    }

    public void going() {
        this.whereAmI += this.speed;
    }
}
```

**Класс раннера:**

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        String stationOne = "Гадюкино";
        String stationTwo = "Ведьмино";
        int countOfWays =1;
        Train trains[] = new Train[13];
        for (int i = 0; i < trains.length; i++) {
            trains[i] = new Train("Поезд № " + i);
            System.out.println(trains[i].getType() + " поезд: " + trains[i].getName() + "\nСкорость движения: " + trains[i].getSpeed() + "\nОтправляется со станции " + stationOne);
        }
        a: while (true) {
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Заезд № "+countOfWays);
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < trains.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(trains[i].getType() + " поезд: " + trains[i].getName() + " начинает движение из точки "+trains[i].getWhereAmI()+ " со скоростью "+trains[i].getSpeed());
                trains[i].going();
                if (trains[i].getWhereAmI()>=100){
                    trains[i].setWhereAmI(100);
                    System.out.println(trains[i].getType() + " поезд: " + trains[i].getName()+" прибыл на станцию "+stationTwo+", совершив "+countOfWays+" заездов");
                    break a;
                }
                System.out.println(trains[i].getType() + " поезд: " + trains[i].getName() + " в точке " + trains[i].getWhereAmI());
            }
            countOfWays++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно же еще проверять все промежуточные точки, а не только последнюю.

Comment: @Эникейщик допустим точки - это просто станции с 1 перроном. Поезда могут перестраиваться на другие ветки, чтобы  обогнать другие поезда на пути. Но подъехать к станции, если там стоит поезд, они не смогут.

Comment: @Anton Sorokin ребят, нет, никаких веток, всё просто - одна линия 0 - 100 и всё)

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин а как тогда поезд проедет по другим поездам стоящим на этой линии?

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин допустим у вас поезд на координате 1, ему надо на координату 5, а на координате 3 уже стоит поезд. Как он проедет через этот поезд? Таранит?

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин P.S. Если мой ответ решил проблему - плюсаните и примите его пожалуйста. ^^ Если нет - напишите почему.

Comment: @AntonSorokin поезда друг друга не обгоняют вообще. Например: 1ый поезд едет первый на 5 шагов. Второй может ехать на 4 и меньше. Если у всех последующих скорость выше 5, то они стоят на месте, пока не уедет 1ый 3им шагом и так далее) Логично, что первым приедет 1ый поезд, вторым -2ой и так далее. Но сам факт, нужно это сделать)

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин так в чем проблема? Вроде мое решение должно работать - оно проверяет, есть ли на точке куда должен поехать поезд какой-нибудь поезд.

Comment: @AntonSorokin теоретически -да, фактически - не работает)

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин само решение рабочее, просто там была опечатка в названии метода

Comment: @AntonSorokin первая часть тоже с ошибкой, не нравится методу в if что мы на вход подаём trains[], i - ругается

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин в чате я написал

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89975/discussion-between---and-anton-sorokin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ни один из ответ до конца не решил проблему. Дело было в методе, который контролировал бы возможность движения каждого поезда. Также пришлось создать вместо обычного массива, лист
Вот что получилось в итоге (класс Train) не изменялся

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        String stationOne = "Гадюкино";
        String stationTwo = "Ведьмино";
        int countOfWays = 0;
        ArrayList<Train> trains = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            trains.add(new Train("Поезд #" + i));
            System.out.println(trains.get(i).getType() + " поезд: " + trains.get(i).getName() + "\nСкорость движения: " + trains.get(i).getSpeed() + "\nОтправляется со станции " + stationOne);
        }
        a:
        while (true) {
            countOfWays++;
            if (trains.size() == 0) {
                break a;
            }
            System.out.println("*** Заезд № " + countOfWays + " ***");
            for (int i = 0; i < trains.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(trains.get(i).getType() + " поезд: " + trains.get(i).getName() + " начинает движение из точки " + trains.get(i).getWhereAmI() + " со скоростью " + trains.get(i).getSpeed());
                if (keepTheDistance(trains, i, countOfWays)) {
                    trains.get(i).going();
                }
                System.out.println(trains.get(i).getType() + " поезд: " + trains.get(i).getName() + " в точке " + trains.get(i).getWhereAmI());
                if (trains.get(i).getWhereAmI() >= 100) {
                    trains.get(i).setWhereAmI(100);
                    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println(trains.get(i).getType() + " поезд: " + trains.get(i).getName() + " прибыл на станцию " + stationTwo + " (точка " + trains.get(i).getWhereAmI() + ")" + ", совершив " + countOfWays + " заездов");
                    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    trains.remove(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean keepTheDistance(ArrayList<Train> trains, int j, int countOfWays) {
        for (int i = 0; i < trains.size(); i++) {
            if (i != j) {
                if (trains.get(j).getWhereAmI() + trains.get(j).getSpeed() == trains.get(i).getWhereAmI()) {
                    if (!(trains.get(j).getWhereAmI() > trains.get(i).getWhereAmI())) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

На выходе все условия выполнились. Задача была решена в соответствии со всеми условиями. @Anton Sorokin @Эникейщик

Comment: @ - в ответах не работают. На первоначальный вопрос мой ответ отвечал. Менять условия вопроса(причем даже не редактируя его, а в чате или комментариях) - плохо.

Comment: @AntonSorokin да я ничего не менял) пояснял же изначально, что поезда друг друга не обгоняют. Читайте в комментариях и в условии. А Ваш ответ помог, но пришлось всё равно самому его дорабатывать в итоге

Comment: Причем тут обгон? Ваш вопрос был такой - как проверить не стоит ли на точке поезд. Мой ответ решал этот вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

`train1` и `train2` - экземпляры класса `Train`.

```
if(train1.getWhereIAm()+train1.getSpeed == train2.getWhereIAm())
  //проезд недоступен
```

На будущее: лучше называть поле не `whereIAm`, а например `coordinate`.

Для вашего примера подойдет проверка с циклом:

```
if(checkCoordinate(trains, i))
  //ехать можно
else
  //ехать нельзя
```

---

`checkCoordinate` - отдельный  метод.

```
private static boolean checkCoordinate(Train trains[], int k) {
  for(int i = 0; i<trains.length; i++)
   if(trains[k].getWhereAmI()+trains[k].getSpeed() == trains[i].getWhereAmI())
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Здесь же сравнивается, где поезда уже стоят, а не куда один из приедет.

Comment: @Эникейщик ааа, ну да. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: @AntonSorokin я не могу подать if(checkCoordinate(trains[], i)) в if

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин что значит подать?

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин сначала скопируйте метод `checkCoordinate` в код

Comment: Всё равно. Сейчас прикреплю к вопросу скрин

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин исправил. Все из-за не очень хорошего названия поля и метода.

Comment: @AntonSorokin вторая часть в норме. Теперь с первой не так, которая в моём методе, в if